# issues upload file to the database using multer in node js

Tags: node.js

I've been learning NodeJS for a while now and I have an issue upload image to the database I've tried everything within my capacity but it not working i hope someone would help me out I'll provide the code which I've tried to work with, but it doesn't work this is my app.js file where i configure the Multer

```
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};
app.use(
  multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single("image")
);
```

in my controller where i try to post the product to the database this is my code

```
exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const image = req.file;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const description = req.body.description;
  if (!image) {
    return res.status(422).render("admin/edit-product", {
      pageTitle: "Add Product",
      path: "/admin/add-product",
      editing: false,
      hasError: true,
      product: {
        title: title,
        price: price,
        description: description,
      },
      errorMessage: "Attached file is not an image.",
      validationErrors: [],
    });
  }
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log(errors.array());
    return res.status(422).render("admin/edit-product", {
      pageTitle: "Add Product",
      path: "/admin/add-product",
      editing: false,
      hasError: true,
      product: {
        title: title,
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        price: price,
        description: description,
      },
      errorMessage: errors.array()[0].msg,
      validationErrors: errors.array(),
    });
  }

  const imageUrl = image.path;

  const product = new Product({
    // _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5badf72403fd8b5be0366e81'),
    title: title,
    price: price,
    description: description,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    userId: req.user,
  });
  product
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      // console.log(result);
      console.log("Created Product");
      res.redirect("/admin/products");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // return res.status(500).render('admin/edit-product', {
      //   pageTitle: 'Add Product',
      //   path: '/admin/add-product',
      //   editing: false,
      //   hasError: true,
      //   product: {
      //     title: title,
      //     imageUrl: imageUrl,
      //     price: price,
      //     description: description
      //   },
      //   errorMessage: 'Database operation failed, please try again.',
      //   validationErrors: []
      // });
      // res.redirect('/500');
      const error = new Error(err);
      error.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(error);
    });
};
```

this is my productSchema file

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  }
});
```

i created an error in my controller

```
exports.get500 = (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).render('500', {
    pageTitle: 'Error!',
    path: '/500',
    isAuthenticated: req.session.isLoggedIn
  });
};
```

but when i try adding procuct to the database i get error would could have been the errror

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: it not showing any error it not allowing me to save my postdata in the database